# how to define __init__ so that it accepts a collection of objects from other classes in Python

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm familiar with the procedural programming in Python. However, I've just started learning classes in python so bear with me if this sounds noob question to you.

I've been following Steve F. Lott's book "Building skills in python" and "Building skills in object oriented design" and am stuck when in exercises he asks me to:

```
Classname.__init__(self,name,symbol,*blocks)
```

Where name and symbol are the symbols of the company.(For a more complete description of the problem- [this](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/book/python-2.6/html/p03/p03c01_class.html#Position.__init__) is what I'm working on). The *blocks is supposed to stand for a collection of another class. Till now I've tried this:

```
class StockBlock():
"""Define a block of stock"""
    def __init__(self,date,price,nos):
         self.date=date
         self.price=price
      self.nos=nos

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %d %d" %(self.date,self.price,self.nos)
    def getPurchValue(self):
        self.Purch_val=self.price*self.nos
        return self.Purch_val
    def getSaleValue(self,salePrice):
        self.SalesVal=salePrice*self.nos
        return self.SalesVal
    def getROI(self,salePrice):
        self.SalesVal=salePrice*self.nos
        roi=((self.SalesVal)-(self.Purch_val))/(self.Purch_val)
        return roi
    def getStock(self):
        return self
```

and

```
def Position(StockBlock):
    def __init__(self,name,sym,*blocks):
                super(StockBlock,self).__init__(*blocks)
                self.name=name
                self.sym=sym
    def __str__(self):
             return "Symbol: %s Total Val:%d" %(self.sym,self.totalval)
    def getPurchValue(self):
         self.totalval=0
         for obj in self._stocks:
              self.totalval+=obj.getPurchValue()
         return self.totalval

    def getSaleValue(self,salePrice):
          self.totalsale=0
          for d in self._stocks:
              self.totalsale+=d.getSaleValue(salePrice)
          return self.totalsale
    def getROI(self,salePrice):
       self.roi=(self.getSaleValue()- self.getPurchValue())/self.getPurchValue()
      return self.roi
```

Can you tell me how do I initialize the Position class with a list of objects from the StockBlock class?

Gracias.

Comment: Note:Python is very sensitive about indentation. There are several indentation errors in your code (`StockBlock.__init__()` and `Position.getROI()`). You have to fix them or Python won't be able to parse your script.

Comment: keep to the Python conventions in PEP8: method names are `lowercase_with_underscore`. All attributes have to be introduced in `__init__`. Instead of the `Get...`-methods use properties.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the concepts of "inheritance" and "composition".

A "truck" is a special kind of "car". For this kind of relation, you use inheritance: `class Truck(Car)`.

But a wheel isn't a car, no matter how you look at it. A cat has 3 or more wheels. It's a **part** so to add wheels to a car-type class, you use composition.

In your code, `Position` isn't a special kind of `StockBlock`, instead it just contains a collection of `StockBlock`. So you need to initialize your class like this:

```
def Position(object):
    def __init__(self,name,sym,*blocks):
        self.name=name
        self.sym=sym
        self.blocks=blocks
```

Related:

- [Re-use in OO: Inheritance, Composition and Mixins](http://naildrivin5.com/blog/2012/12/19/re-use-in-oo-inheritance.html)
- [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: But then I'm passing a tuple to a list. Wouldn't be that an error?

Comment: [Here](https://bitbucket.org/ankit_kulshrestha/oop_python/raw/b5aa59b2f0ea78b9f7e360efa96c1db1b1b53a3e/position.py) is the code.

Comment: @AnkitKulshrestha: Access denied. Please copy&paste the relevant part into your question.

Comment: I guess that's my private repository. Anyway, I was able to get around the problem. Thanks for your massive help.